# MYSQL (via WAMP) long update query time

Tags: mysql

I have spent several weeks crunching on this to no avail, so I'm hopeful you may be able to help.  Generally, I have an update query that takes forever to run (I've given up after 12 hours).  To knock the obvious out of the way, I have an index on the columns.  Also, I am totally self-taught on MYSQL, so I may need additional clarification on data / processes etc.  This DB is for my personal use, offline.  Said another way... this is not my day job.  While I enjoy MYSQL, I am not a super-user.

**First, my system specs...**

- Laptop Samsung QX410
- Windows 7, 64 bit
- Intel i5, M 480 @ 2.67 GHz
- RAM: 8 GB (7.79 available)
- WAMP 2.5 with MYSQL v5.6.17
- Tables are INNODB

MYSQL set up:

```
' The MySQL server  
[wampmysqld]  
port        = 3306  
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock  
key_buffer_size = 512M  
max_allowed_packet = 32M  
sort_buffer_size = 512K  
net_buffer_length = 32K  
read_buffer_size = 256K  
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K  
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M  
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17  
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log  
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data  

' Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables  
innodb_data_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/  
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend  
innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/  
innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\mysql\data/  
' You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %  
' of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high  
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4000M  
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 32M  
' Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size  
innodb_log_file_size = 512M  
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M  
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0  
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

Issue in more detail:

I have two tables Trade_List and Cusip_Table and am trying to populate one column in Trade_List (I need to pre-populate this value, since many queries will be run against it).

**Trade_List has 11 columns, two of which are relevant.**

- CUSIP (varchar 45) - generally this is a 9 digit alpha-numeric number.
- TICKER (varchar 45) - generally this is 10 letters or less.  I want to populate this.

This table has roughly 10 million rows.
I have removed all indices from this table except one on CUSIP.

**Cusip_Table has 5 columns, two of which are relevant.**

- CUSIP (varchar 45) - generally this is a 9 digit alpha-numeric number.
- TICKER (varchar 45) - generally this is 10 letters or less.  This is already populated.

This table has roughly 70,000 rows.
I have an index 'CTDuplicateCheck' on (Cusip, Ticker).

When I run...

```
Select A.cusip, B.ticker  
From Trade_list A, Cusip_table B  
Where A.cusip = B.cusip;
```

... MYSQL indicates that the query takes about 13 seconds, but in reality it seems to take about a minute, so I ran profiling on it...

```
starting                0.000093  
checking permissions    0.000006  
checking permissions    0.000005  
Opening tables          0.000041  
init                    0.000037  
System lock             0.000013  
optimizing              0.000015  
statistics              0.000041  
preparing               0.000030  
executing               0.000002  
Sending data           10.982211  
end                     0.000014  
query end               0.000010  
closing tables          0.000018  
freeing items           0.000070  
logging slow query      0.000004  
cleaning up             0.000019
```

I don't know what any of this means, but 10 seconds for sending data seems reasonable (the return set is ~9M rows.

Just for kicks, and to make sure the index is working, I ran an 'explain' (shown below).  I think this says that my index is working correctly.

```
1   SIMPLE  B   index   CTDuplicateCheck    CTDuplicateCheck    96      53010                        Using where; Using index  
1   SIMPLE  A   ref     TL1Cusip            TL1Cusip            48      13f_master_data.B.CUSIP 154 Using index
```

**NOTE: 13f_Master_Data is the name of the database.

At any rate, when I run the same query, but change it to an update, everything falls apart and it will not complete.  I would expect things to run a bit slower, but 12 hours +?  I just can't imagine that this is normal for an update query that touches 9M rows.  The original INSERT took less than an hour, and the select takes less than a minute.  Code for the update is below...

```
Update Trade_list A, Cusip_table B 
Set A.ticker = B.ticker
Where A.cusip = B.cusip;
```

Stuff I have tried:

- Removed almost all index's from Trade_List.  I left one in on CUSIP.
- Upgraded RAM from 4 GB to 8 GB.  This did nothing.  Upon further investigation, my CPU and RAM are not limiting factors.  CPU generally sits around 30%, RAM never gets above 5GB utilized.  This leads me to believe that the issue is I/O.  Is it possible MYSQL is doing a full table-scan?  Why would it not utilize the index?
- Changed all types of memory allocations per http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/09/20/innodb-performance-optimization-basics-updated/ and https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/mysqltuner/ and http://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/.  As far as I can tell, this did nothing.  Again, I don't think the limiting factor is memory available.  Also, I have no doubt that my memory allocations (shown above) are completely screwed up.  I had no idea what I was doing and changed things all over the place.  That said, I don't think the memory changes made anything any worse.
- Upgraded MYSQL and Wamp versions (did nothing).
- Read and learned a lot about index's.  Candidly, I know very little about MYSQL, and am totally self-taught.  I have learned a lot about memory on this foray, but need someone to step in and tell me where I have totally derailed.  This database is for my own offline analysis.  I am the only user.

I am happy to provide additional information that may help to analyze the issue.  I'm at a total loss on this.  The only thing I can come up with is that the system is doing full scans row by row... for every look-up in the update.  Though, this could be completely false.

Your thoughts are much appreciated.
PM

Comment: How many rows will the update affect? It could very well be that you are running out of memory and the database is swapping to disk which will slow down thing immensely. Most people always buy bigger memory and CPU's while neglecting the slowest part of a computer the good old fashioned hard drive(not the new fancy flash drives).

Comment: The update will affect all ~9M rows.  How would I calculate the memory needs for the update?

Comment: That is going to be tricky.  Break the update into batches. I suspect you are just running into swapping issue. Update 1000 rows at a time for example and see if there is a difference.

Comment: YOu have 8GB of ram and 7.79 available? Which version of windows do you run? I want it....

Comment: I ran for 1,000 rows (0.3 seconds), 10,000 rows (1.4 seconds), 100,000 rows (6.4 seconds), 1,000,000 rows (84 seconds).

Comment: So if you split your data into 1 M blocks and update them in sequence, the full 9 M rows will be updated in 756 seconds (13 minutes). Divide and conquer is frequently a good strategy. Divide your data in nine chunks and update them in sequence. You can even create a stored procedure to do the work for you

Comment: By the way, if your question has nothing to do with SQL server, why do you use the sql-server tag? (I've just removed it)

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Is there a way to write the code to run a loop rather than including the same code 9 times?  Alternatively,  which memory buffer would be running out?  Is it something I can tweak the settings on?